# Using Scrapy to get all the articles

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using this script with Scrapy :

```
import scrapy


class PageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "page"
    start_urls = ['http://blog.theodo.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for article_url in response.css('.Link-sc-19p3alm-0 fnuPWK a ::attr("href")').extract():
            yield response.follow(article_url, callback=self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        content = response.xpath(".//div[@class='entry-content']/descendant::text()").extract()
        yield {'article': ''.join(content)}
```

I'm following a tutorial but some part needed to be changed I guess.

I have already changed :

```
response.css('.Link-sc-19p3alm-0 fnuPWK a ::attr("href")').extract():
```

I guess this is what I need to get the link of the article ->

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyQfE.jpg)

But I'm stuck with the xpath. All the content of the article is contained in a div but there is no entry-content anymore :

[xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNF6u.png)

I would like to know if I put the the right thing in the response.css and also whak kind of path I need to write in xpath and understand the logic behind.

Thanks you, I'm hoping my post is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think you need an extra point before *fnuPWK* like:

```
response.css('.Link-sc-19p3alm-0 .fnuPWK a ::attr("href")').extract()
```

Because I think it is a class.

Also good to know is that you can copy Xpath, CSS selectors etc with element inspect (see example in the picture below). This way you are sure that you have the right Xpath.
[Chrome inspect element copy XPath example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmBC1.png)

Comment: i always try my xpath expressions first in scrapy shell, to check, if they work or not. If yes, you can easily copy+paste into your code.
Just a little note x)

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal, write scrapy shell 'blog.theodo.com'

for the href element you have to do:

response.xpath('//a[@class="Link-sc-19p3alm-0 fnuPWK"]/@href').get()

Also i cant give you an example of the "text", because your picture does not show enough information for me.

Also keep in mind: if you use ' as your first quotation marks, you have to use after class= double quotation marks for example('//div[@class=""]')

for the whole article on https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/dynamiser-vos-equipes-special-post-confinement/

response.xpath('//div[@class="course-des-content"]//text()').getall()

.get() will provide you the first match, but in that case, getall would suit more imo

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223493/discussion-on-answer-by-y-y-using-scrapy-to-get-all-the-articles).